# Unit testing documentation for Vuetify is not compatible with latest release of @vue/test-utils. I need help setting up vitest

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I've learned that `createLocalVue` no longer exists in Vue test utils, making this [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#test-runners) outdated.

Here are the specs for my project:

- Laravel 9 (w/ Vite)
- Vue 3
- Inertia.js
- JavaScript
- Vuetify 3
- Testing

  - Vitest
  - Vue Test Utils

Here is what my vite.config.js looks like.

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import DefineOptions from 'unplugin-vue-define-options/vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        deps: {
            inline: ["vuetify"],
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    // The Vue plugin will re-write asset URLs, when referenced
                    // in Single File Components, to point to the Laravel web
                    // server. Setting this to `null` allows the Laravel plugin
                    // to instead re-write asset URLs to point to the Vite
                    // server instead.
                    base: null,

                    // The Vue plugin will parse absolute URLs and treat them
                    // as absolute paths to files on disk. Setting this to
                    // `false` will leave absolute URLs un-touched so they can
                    // reference assets in the public directory as expected.
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        vuetify({
            autoImport: true
        }),
        DefineOptions(),
    ],
});
```

And here is the sample code for one of my tests.

```
import {describe, expect, test} from 'vitest';
import Home from "../Pages/Home.vue";
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('Home.vue', () => {
    test("invoice pagination", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Home, {
            props: {
                invoicePagination: {
                    total: 0,
                    per_page: 5,
                    current_page: 1,
                    last_page: 1,
                    first_page_url: "https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1",
                    last_page_url: "https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1",
                    prev_page_url: null,
                    next_page_url: null,
                    path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices",
                    from: 1,
                    to: 1,
                    data: [],
                }
            },
        });

        expect(2 + 2 === 4);
    })
})
```

I get this output in the terminal when running `vitest`.

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(vuetify:display)" not found. 
  at <Home invoicePagination= {
  total: 0,
  per_page: 5,
  current_page: 1,
  last_page: 1,
  first_page_url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1',
  last_page_url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1',
  prev_page_url: null,
  next_page_url: null,
  path: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices',
  from: 1,
  to: 1,
  data: []
} ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: undefined. 
  at <Home invoicePagination= {
  total: 0,
  per_page: 5,
  current_page: 1,
  last_page: 1,
  first_page_url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1',
  last_page_url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices?page=1',
  prev_page_url: null,
  next_page_url: null,
  path: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices',
  from: 1,
  to: 1,
  data: []
} ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>

 ❯ resources/js/Tests/Home.spec.js (1)
   ❯ Home.vue (1)
     × invoice pagination

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Tests 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

 FAIL  resources/js/Tests/Home.spec.js > Home.vue > invoice pagination
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')
 ❯ Proxy._sfc_render resources/js/Pages/Home.vue:61:54
     59|         </v-col>
     60|     </v-row>
     61|     <v-row id="empty-result" v-if="invoicePagination.total === 0">
       |                                                      ^
     62|         <v-col>
     63|             <NoInvoicesPicture v-if="!smAndDown"></NoInvoicesPicture>
 ❯ renderComponentRoot node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:891:44
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5570:57
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.run node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:191:25
 ❯ instance.update node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5684:56
 ❯ setupRenderEffect node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5698:9
 ❯ mountComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5480:9
 ❯ processComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5438:17
 ❯ patch node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5042:21
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5577:21

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/1]⎯

 Test Files  1 failed (1)
      Tests  1 failed (1)
   Start at  09:26:11
   Duration  4.12s (transform 2.03s, setup 0ms, collect 2.37s, tests 34ms)


 FAIL  Tests failed. Watching for file changes...
       press h to show help, press q to quit
```

I'm concerned about "injection "Symbol(vuetify:display)" not found." I believe it's causing my test to fail.

Without accurate docs, I don't know how to employ Vuetify with my configuration.